# POST method cannot redirect to HTML page(Backend Flask, Frontend Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am trying to use value of dropdown from frontend to backend where on behalf of the dropdown value calculation will be happened and that endpoint will return a HTML page.
Would like to add that, I don't need to get any response from the POST method (eg: `return jsonify`). So far, I am using `Flask` for backend and for frontend `Vanilla JS`.

I have successfully pass and fetched dropdown value using POST method in backend. I have also checked from server and browser console and no error found.

The approach I have taken do far:

#### Frontend

##### HTML file, written in index.html

```html
<label for="mode">Select Mode:</label>
<select id="mode" name="mode">
    <option value="autoencoder">Autoencoder</option>
    <option value="decoder">Decoder</option>
</select>
<button id="Module_submitBtn">Chose Module</button>

<script src="static/js/call_module.js "></script>
```

##### JS file

```js
function submitMode() {
    var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;

    fetch('/update_mode', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ mode: selectedMode })
    })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

const submitBtn = document.getElementById('Module_submitBtn');
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', submitMode);
```

#### Backend

##### python file

```py
# This is the desired endpiunt from where HTML file is rendered
@app.route("/decoder_graphical_view", methods=['GET'])
def decoder_graphical_view(name=None):
    config_val = Decoder_Config.config_val
    return render_template("decoder_graph.html",
                           N_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["N_"],
                           ebno_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["ebno_"],
                           phi_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["phi_"],
                           learningRate_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["learning_rate_"],
                           name=name
                           )

# This is the endpoint where POST method will work, dropdown value will come and it will call `decoder_graphical_view` function
@app.route('/update_mode', methods=['POST'])
def update_mode(name=None):
    selected_mode = request.json.get('mode')

    if selected_mode == 'autoencoder':

        return redirect(url_for('decoder_graphical_view'))


    elif selected_mode == 'decoder':
        return redirect(url_for('decoder_graphical_view'))
```

I have also tried the `update_mode function` in the following way but same result and failed.

```py
@app.route('/update_mode', methods=['POST'])
def update_mode(name=None):
    selected_mode = request.json.get('mode')
    # set default value for the config data
    Decoder_Config.config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["N_"]     = 100
    Decoder_Config.config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["ebno_"]  = 2.0
    Decoder_Config.config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["phi_"]   = 5
    Decoder_Config.config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["train_"] = "True"
    train_var = str(Decoder_Config.config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["train_"]).lower()
    if train_var == "true":
        train_var = True
    else:
        train_var = False
    Decoder_Config.config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["learning_rate_"]   = 0.005

    if selected_mode == 'autoencoder':
        print("selected_mode: ", selected_mode)
        return render_template("decoder_graph.html",
                                N_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["N_"],
                                ebno_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["ebno_"],
                                phi_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["phi_"],
                                learningRate_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["learning_rate_"],
                                name=name
                                )

    elif selected_mode == 'decoder':
        return render_template("decoder_graph.html",
                                N_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["N_"],
                                ebno_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["ebno_"],
                                phi_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["phi_"],
                                learningRate_value=config_val["Decoder_live_plot"]["learning_rate_"],
                                name=name
                                )
```

#### Trial

So far what I have tried are listed below: [1](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_flask_example/blob/main/app.py#L65), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/oscqgt/how_to_redirect_page_after_post/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69846684/unable-to-redirect-to-another-route-in-flask), though could not get any valid result.

In server console I have seen the following message while I have pressed `Submit button`

```
"POST /update_mode HTTP/1.1" 302 -
"GET /decoder_graphical_view HTTP/1.1" 200
```

What could be the possible way to get a rendered HTML after calling the POST method?

Comment: based on your js file /update_mode is the route. Your fetch is not handling any response assuming your backend is returning something. I would consider using asyn/await and handle the response from post to display web? 
https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on behalf of the dropdown value calculation will be happened and that
> endpoint will return a HTML page

This sounds like task for plain FORM, consider following example

templates/index.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/current">
<label for="what">I want to know current</label>
<select name="what" id="what">
<option value="y">year</option>
<option value="m">month</option>
<option value="d">value</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

templates/current.html

```
<html>
<body>
{{answer}}
</body>
</html>
```

application.py

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.get("/")
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")
@app.post("/current")
def current():
    what = request.form["what"]
    today = datetime.date.today()
    if what=="y":
        answer = today.strftime("Year is %Y")
    elif what=="m":
        answer = today.strftime("Month is %m")
    elif what=="d":
        answer = today.strftime("Day is %d")
    else:
        answer = "Not supported"
    return render_template("current.html", answer=answer)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

*(tested in Flask 2.3.2)*

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `index.html` is also within the Flask app templates, otherwise you'd have to provide the url, instead of just the `/update_mode` path, when calling `fetch` in your javascript module.

To redirect from the response you're getting from the backend, you just have to change `window.location.href` to the `url` passed in the redirect response model sent from the backend. Something like this:

```js
fetch('/update_mode', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ mode: selectedMode })
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.redirected) {
                window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```